# Why don't gas calculations take into account array size anymore?

Tags: gas, gas-estimate

I clearly remember that a couple of months ago when I tried to push some items into a storage array each consecutive 'array-pushing-transaction' took more gas to execute. In other words, it was increasingly expensive to use arrays. Now it seems that the things have changed -- gas calculations dont't take into account array size anymore. I'm just curious when did these changes took place and what was the reason behind such limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [storage layout](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage) with "The mapping or the dynamic array itself occupies..." you will see that all actions are `O(1)`, keccak256 calculations and read / writes.

I do not understand where you got this increasing cost. It must have been something elsewhere in the function.

Comment: I have heard this exact sort of thing from otherwise well-informed sources. I think they're conflating an implied increase in the number of operations at larger scales, with increasing cost of individual operations. In other words, a hidden assumption that all algos cost more at scale and confusing that with increasing EVM costs.

Comment: @Xavier Leprêtre B9lab, thank you,  it just dawned on me that it might have been a bug in solidity online compiler